# Inherit Interface or class properties into derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to inherit my interface or class properties into derived class as a properties here is my code:

```
  public class Login : Customer
{
    ??
}
interface Customer
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string pdw { get; set; }
}
```

but i'm unable to do that, please suggest me the best possible way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You don't *inherit* from interfaces, you *implement* them. Since an interface has no implementation of its own, its up to you to implement the properties within your own class.

Comment: You inherit from other classes, not from interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify code in an interface, so there is nothing to inherit. A class *implements* an interface, it does not *inherit* it.

However, if you want to provide code for a derived class, you can just write a base class to contain it.

Often you want to provide a base class that implements some - but not all - of an interface. You can do that by writing an *abstract* base class that implements part of an interface, and declares the unimplemented methods as *abstract*.

An example will clarify:

```
interface ICustomer
{
    string Name     { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }

    string SomeOtherMethod();
}

public abstract class CustomerBase : ICustomer
{
    public string Name     { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // We do not implement SomeOtherMethod() here.
    // Instead, make it abstract to force a non-abstract derived class to implement it:

    public abstract string SomeOtherMethod();
}

class Login: CustomerBase
{
    // This class does not need to implement Name or Password,
    // because it can inherit them from CustomerBase.
    // However it must still implement SomeOtherMethod()
    // because that method is declared abstract in the base class.

    public override string SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        return "Implemented by me";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this example, i think your going down the wrong route.

Inheritance is different to Implementing an Interface.

An Interface is more like a contract, in which a class that implements it must adhere too :-

```
public interface ISendMessage
{
    void Send();
}

public class SmsSender : ISendMessage
{
    public void Send()
    {
        // Code to send SMS
    }
}

public class EmailSender : ISendMessage
{
    public void Send()
    {
        // Code to send Email
    }
}
```

Inheritence, is generally used where you have a class thats a base, that other similar classes can inherit its base properties.

An example base class, would be Vehicle :-

```
 public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int ManufactureYear { get; set; }
        public string RegNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }
```

All properties of the Vehicle class apply to a Truck, a Motorbike, Car, or Bus.

But a Motorbike and a Car have different properties that cant be sahredlike this :-

```
 public class MotorBike : Vehicle
    {

    }

    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }
        public int NumberofSeatBelts { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the interface.

```
interface Customer
{
   // Property signatures: 
   string Name 
   {
      get;
      set;
   }

   string pdw 
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

class Login : Customer
{
   // Fields: 
   private string _name;
   private string _pdw;

   // Constructor: 
   public Login ()
   {

   }

   // Property implementation: 
   public string name
   {
      get
      {
         return _name;
      }

      set
      {
         _name = value;
      }
   }

   public string pdw
   {
      get
      {
         return _pdw;
      }
      set
      {
         _pdw = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Login : ICustomer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pdw { get; set; }
}

interface ICustomer
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Pdw { get; set; }
}

var loginModel = new Login();

//then access loginModel.Name & loginModel.Pdw
```

Always use a upper approach for your properties. Pdw not pdw.

And always declare your interfaces with ISomething like ICustomer, not Customer.

Basically having interfaces for your models is damaging (long-term project) or at least this is my point of view.

Keep interfaces for architecture, repositories, buses and so on.

And keep your models idempotent and without dependencies. (or at least not so many dependencies)

^ Where dependencies equals interfaces or other classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about another take on this? Instead of an `interface`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string pdw { get; set; }
}

public class Login : Customer
{

}
```

The `Login` class now has access to the base class properties instead of having to implement them itself.

Of course if you have no control over the use of the original interface, then disregard this answer as it is just a means to show another method.